# PHP $_GET returns index.php

Tags: php, .htaccess, get

I'm running a simple script and I want to use $_GET['id']; to get a certain value from the URL.

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

**My PHP**

```
$getID = $_GET['id'];
echo $getID;
```

**My URL**

```
http://www.test.com/5/
```

**Output**

```
index.php
```

**Output Desired**

```
5
```

I've sat for nearly an hour trying to figure out why it's not working.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: I think it's applying the same rewrite again. You should find a rewrite condition to keep it from rewriting calls to your index.php. To name a few options: There's an [END] flag you could try or use the following conditions: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d. Those will cause the rewrite to only happen for urls that are not valid files or directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change [L] to [QSA]

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [QSA]
```

Comment: @JorenVanSeveren why not make it a question? lets see what other people say?

Comment: @JorenVanSeveren see this example: http://hostfrosh.org/JorenQSA/5/ and this http://hostfrosh.org/Joren/5/ and decide then!!!

Comment: Changing to QSA did work for me.  Everything functions correctly now.  Thanks!